# Callers block until getFoo() has a value ready?

Tags: java, multithreading, properties, synchronization, blocking

I have a Java `Thread` which exposes a property which other threads want to access:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
   private Foo foo;
   ...
   Foo getFoo() {
     return foo;
   }
   ...
   public void run() { 
     ...
     foo = makeTheFoo();
     ...
   }
}
```

The problem is that it takes some short time from the time this runs until `foo` is available. Callers may call `getFoo()` before this and get a `null`. I'd rather they simply block, wait, and get the value once initialization has occurred. (`foo` is never changed afterwards.) It will be a matter of milliseconds until it's ready, so I'm comfortable with this approach.

Now, I can make this happen with `wait()` and `notifyAll()` and there's a 95% chance I'll do it right. But I'm wondering how you all would do it; is there a primitive in `java.util.concurrent` that would do this, that I've missed?

Or, how would you structure it? Yes, make `foo` volatile. Yes, synchronize on an internal lock `Object` and put the check in a `while` loop until it's not `null`. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `foo` is initialized only one time, a [`CountDownLatch`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is a great fit.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

  private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  ...

  Foo getFoo() throws InterruptedException
  {
    latch.await(); /* Or use overload with timeout parameter. */
    return foo;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    foo = makeTheFoo()
    latch.countDown();
  }

}
```

Latches provide the same visibility behavior as the `volatile` keyword, meaning that reading threads will see the value of `foo` assigned by the thread, even though `foo` isn't declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 3):

In general notify() and notifyAll() are the methods you want. notify() is dangerous if only one item is creating the Foo and many threads might wait for it. But I think there are some other issues here.

I wouldn't make the Thread the place to store the Foo. Doing so means you have to keep a thread around after Foo is created. Why not make another object to store the Foo, and have the creating thread write to it?

Then I would have getFoo() test foo and only wait if it was non-null (don't forget to synchronize it with itself and with the foo setter).

Comment: Agree, I wish it weren't so. In this case I really have to make the object within run(). It's a GUI app with weird needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `CountDownLatch`:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
   private volatile CountDownLatch latch;
   private Foo foo;
   MyThread(){
      latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
   }
   ...
   Foo getFoo() {
     latch.await(); // waits until foo is ready
     return foo;
   }
   ...
   public void run() { 
     ...
     foo = makeTheFoo();
     latch.countDown();// signals that foo is ready
     ...
   }
}
```

I don't think `wait`/`notifyAll` will work, because every `wait` will expect a `notify`. You want to notify once and then never bother with notification again, then any other thread that's calling `getFoo` will either block until `foo` is initialized or just get `foo` if it's already initialized.

Comment: Actually, there's a subtle bug here: since `latch` isn't `final` or `volatile`, it's not guaranteed to be "visible" to other threads. Might not be an issue in practice, but the guarantee doesn't really cost anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use any of the [`BlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)'s in `java.util.concurrent` More specifically, if there is one thread waiting for Foo and one producing it I'd use a [`SynchronousQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) in cases of more producers and/or more consumers my default option is a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), but other implementations might be better suited to your application. Your code then becomes:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
   private SynchronousQueue<Foo> queue = new SynchronousQueue<Foo>();
   ...
   Foo getFoo() {
     Foo foo;
     try {
        foo = queue.take();
     }
     catch (InteruptedException ex) {
        ...stuff ...
     }
     return foo;
   }
   ...
   public void run() { 
     ...
     foo = makeTheFoo();
     try {
        queue.put(foo);
     }
     catch (InteruptedException ex) {
        ...stuff ...
     }
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: SynchronousQueue is a handy construct in many cases, but it doesn't fit the requirement here very well: `foo` is only initialized once, and read possibly many times. This would only allow `foo` to be read once. Other attempts to read the property would block forever.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I had missed the "only initialized once" part. I thought this was more of a producer/consumer situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the wait() and notify() methods:

Simple example here:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=306

Comment: Definitely, I can roll a solution by hand. I think it's a tad more complex than this -- the field should be `volatile` and we need `notifyAll()` to start -- so I was hoping for comments on what else I need, or a pre-packaged solution that's definitely right.

Comment: @Sean In that case I would go with DJClayworth's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, concurrent stuff is created explicitly not to wait and do what you want right away — but if it is possible at all.  In your case you need to wait until something is available, so your only option is, uh, to `wait()`.  In short, it seems that the way you described it is the only correct way.

Answer (score 0):

If initialization is a one shot deal, try [java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is lazy initialization an option?

```
synchronized Foo getFoo() {
    if (foo == null)
        foo = makeFoo();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: Not in this case since the foo must be made in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try my fancy FutureValue class...

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class FutureValue<T> {
private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
private T value;

public void set(T value) throws InterruptedException, IllegalStateException {
    if (latch.getCount() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Value has been already set.");
    }
    latch.countDown();
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * Returns the value stored in this container. Waits if value is not available.
 * 
 * @return
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public T get() throws InterruptedException {
    latch.await();
    return value;
}

}

// Usage example
class MyExampleClass {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static void usageExample() throws InterruptedException {
    FutureValue<String> futureValue = new FutureValue<>();

    // the thread that will produce the value somewhere
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                futureValue.set("this is future");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).run();

    String valueProducedSomewhereElse = futureValue.get();
}
}
```